# Optimise a query

Tags: php, mysql

Would love some help on optimising a MySQL query using indexes (or indeed, the query itself).

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `match_current` (
  `partnership_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `runs` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `balls` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user1_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `user1_firstname` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `user1_lastname` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `user1_runs` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user1_balls` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user1_strike` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user1_out` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user1_retired` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user2_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `user2_firstname` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `user2_lastname` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `user2_runs` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user2_balls` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user2_strike` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user2_out` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user2_retired` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_over` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `ball_by_ball` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `facebook` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `friends` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nudge` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `started` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`partnership_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user1_id_2` (`user1_id`,`user2_id`,`facebook`),
  KEY `user2_id` (`user2_id`),
  KEY `user1_id` (`user1_id`),
  KEY `facebook` (`facebook`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `friends` (`friends`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `user1_id_3` (`user1_id`,`user1_strike`),
  KEY `user2_id_2` (`user2_id`,`user2_strike`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=36139 ;
```

Sample Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM match
WHERE status = 1 
AND (
  (user1_id=1234 AND user1_strike=1) OR 
  (user2_id=4321 AND user2_strike=1)
) 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

The query obviously works and wasn't doing too bad but we've really increased traffic recently and now I can see it's starting to struggle.

Cheers!

Comment: In order to optimise it, people would also need to know what the table structure/indexes is. Consider adding output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE match` to your question.

Comment: What columns would You like to set indexes on? Indexes are for string mathcing and searching, not for number or datetime columns...

Comment: You need to show us what indexes you have.

Comment: The first thing that springs to mind immediately, is do you really need **everything** from the table (i.e. `SELECT *`)?

Comment: Start by not using * but a list of really usefull fields

Comment: I literally use every field from the table in this query. Does it make the query leaner by actually referring to each field individually?

Comment: It probably won't affect performance in this case, but listing the selected fields makes the code more readable as other employees won't have to check the schema to know what you're actually selecting.

Comment: I've added the table structure to the question along with the current indexes I'm using.

Comment: Just a suggestion - if you need to reuse the results of the query and have an option to cache the results - it would take a lot of load of the server. For example, you might create a PHP class with fields that match the fields from the table, and store this result in the $_GLOBALS or $_SESSION[] variables.

Comment: Your indexes look OK, at least for the sample query. ~36k rows aren't too much either. Is the query slow because you have too much data or too much traffic?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind while optimizing queries is that MySQL will only choose *one index* when it performs the query; blindly indexing any combinations of fields you can think of may not help much and in fact slows down inserts.

This look like a typical table with two players forming a team, so because you're not sure whether the queried user will be in `user1` or `user2` you search for both. This is most likely causing all keys to be rejected and a table scan is performed as a result.

My advice would be to slightly denormalize your table and create a separate table where you store `(user_id, partnership_id)` coupled with a spanning primary key, each record in `partnerships` is two records in this table; this eliminates the `OR` and you can use a simple `JOIN` to get the information you need from the bigger table.

To help you investigate these issues you can use `EXPLAIN <query>` to see how MySQL "attacks" your query.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need everything?

```
SELECT *
```

Create indexes, for the WHERE clause

```
INDEX(user1_id, user1_strike, user2_id, user2_strike)
```

You could also include the timestemp and set the ordering to ASC in the index.

Beside these maybe the database's tables need additional indexing and maybe redesigning. Also consider to check the SQL server settings (use InnoDB tables, and set the correct cache/memory limits for the server).

Comment: Here's a thought, let's put an index on the kitchen sink as well.